# Removing extra white spaces from beginning of textarea in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-7

I have displayed some text data in  `<textarea>` tag after getting the data form controller. But the text have extra white spaces at the beginning.

[image]

Comment: Any code to show?

Comment: `ltrim()` removes whitespaces from the left

Comment: If that is a browser only one whitespace character would display. Is a WYSIWYG being used and perhaps you have `&nbsp;`s or `&$160;`s? Please show what you've tried and what the actual string starts off with.

Answer (score 1):

For this Case PHP has some built-in functions.
At the end of the answer, i will provide the direct links to the docs.

In your case you should use the **trim()** Method.
This simply strips the whitespaces from the beginning and the end of the string.

```
<?php
    $textarea = "       Lorem ipsum dolor      ";
    $trimmed_textarea = trim($textarea); //this returns the $textarea string without whitespaces
    echo $trimmed_textarea;
?>
```

If you need further instructions, you can look into the docs of the trim function.
[trim()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.trim.php)

Answer (score 0):

//in controller

```
$texts = "this is very very long text"; //you might retrieve from database
```

//final use

```
trim($texts);
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating this `$message ?? ''` to this `$message` in the .html file fixed the issue for me